# jQuery Mobile Ajax Navigation - Find whether or not a page was navigated 'back' to

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a listview that contains links to view the full content. When I click back from the full content page, the list reloads from scratch...obviously not the best experience. I've found that adding data-dom-cache="true" can bring the user straight back to the list item, which is great! However, when the user hits 'back' (the data-rel='back' button), on pageload/whatever for the list page it's loading (well, reloading) the list.

Is there a way to determine whether or not the user has hit 'back'?
What I'd like to do is basically:

if (variableforuserhitback = false) {
do the code to get the listview
}

Otherwise (hitback = true) just leave it alone and run no code.

I tried going through the docs under ajax navigation, but am not really sure where to find something usable to determine whether or not the user hit back. (some kind of navigation index -1?) It seems like this is something simple that I'm just missing.

Comment: Which event are you using to load the list? If you bind to `pageinit`, the handler will not run if the page is shown again from cache.

Comment: Thanks for the 'pageinit' recommendation. I had to switch some stuff around: adding data-dom-cache="true" to the page and .remove() the when generally navigated to the page, also turning off prefetching. Seems to work well now.

Comment: On second review it looks like page init is causing insane bug issues...so back to the original question.